# Accessing External Database on an Android app

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I am accessing an external database(000webhost) for fetching the email address in the app and printing them into a `ListView`. I am getting the correct response from the server which is printing in the logcat, but I am getting a `null pointer exception`. 
This is what my logcat looks like:

```
05-11 16:00:39.891  24149-24914/info.androidhive.loginandregistration E/Entity Response:﹕ {"email":[{"email":"adeel@gmail.com"},{"email":"yamini@gmail.com"},{"email":"mona@gmail.com"}]}{"tag":"DisplayFriends","error":true,"error_msg":"Unknown 'tag' value. It should be either 'login' or 'register'"}
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
 05-11 16:00:39.895  24149-24149/info.androidhive.loginandregistration    D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
 05-11 16:00:39.898  24149-24149/info.androidhive.loginandregistration  E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: info.androidhive.loginandregistration, PID: 24149
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.FriendsList.setListAdapter(FriendsList.java:55)
        at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.FriendsList$GetAllCustomerTask.onPostExecute(FriendsList.java:74)
        at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.FriendsList$GetAllCustomerTask.onPostExecute(FriendsList.java:60)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Following are my java files:
ApiConnector.java

```
  public class ApiConnector {

Global g=Global.getInstance();
String a=g.getLogInEmail();
String b="DisplayFriends";


public JSONArray GetAllCustomers()
{
    // URL for getting all customers


   // String url = "http://z.locationtest.comxa.com/index.php?tag=DisplayFriends&loggedInEmail="+a;
    String url = "http://z.locationtest.comxa.com/index.php";
    // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
    // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object

    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    try
    {


        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", b));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loggedInEmail", a));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
       // HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

       HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        // Signals error in http protocol
        e.printStackTrace();

        //Log Errors Here



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
   JSONArray jsonArray=null;
    JSONObject jsonObject =null;

    if (httpEntity != null)
    {
        try
        {
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            Log.e("Entity Response: ", entityResponse);
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(entityResponse);

            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("email");
            // jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
            /*for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("TAG_LOCATIONS", jsonArray.toString(i));

            }*/
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

  return jsonArray;


}


}
```

FriendList.java

```
   public class FriendsList extends Activity {

 private ListView listViewFriends;
 private JSONArray jsonArray;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.listViewFriends=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listViewFriends);

    new GetAllCustomerTask().execute(new ApiConnector());




 }
void setListAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray)
 {
 //this.jsonArray=jsonArray;
  this.listViewFriends.setAdapter(new GetAllFriendsListViewAdapter(jsonArray,this));
}



private class GetAllCustomerTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,JSONArray>
{
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {

        // it is executed on Background thread

        return params[0].GetAllCustomers();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray)
    {

        setListAdapter(jsonArray);

    }
    }
    }
```

GetAllFriendsListViewAdapter.java

```
  public class GetAllFriendsListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {
   private JSONArray dataArray;
   private Activity activity;
  private static LayoutInflater inflater= null;


  public GetAllFriendsListViewAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray, Activity a)
  {
    this.activity=a;
    this.dataArray=jsonArray;
    inflater=     (LayoutInflater)this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

   }
   @Override
  public int getCount()
   {
    return this.dataArray.length();

   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position)
  {
    return position;

    }

    @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
    ListCell cell;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout,null);
        cell=new ListCell();
        cell.email=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFriends);

       convertView.setTag(cell);

    }
    else
    {
            cell=(ListCell)convertView.getTag();
    }
    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = this.dataArray.getJSONObject(position);
        cell.email.setText(" "+jsonObject.getString("email"));
    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;
}


private class ListCell
{
    private TextView email;
}

}
```

I am new to Android. It would be great if someone help me find the error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

> A NullPointerException is thrown at runtime whenever your program
>   attempts to use a null as if it was a real reference.

So the error is not in getting the data from wherever you are hosting it. It is because you are trying to use a variable which is null.
You have done this `private JSONArray jsonArray;` but you need to do this too `variable = new variable-type();` to allocate memory too. 
Please check the part above and do some googling. There is no error in getting the data, it is happening when you try to do something with it.

You are just declaring variables as below

```
private ListView listViewFriends;
 private JSONArray jsonArray;
```

But this is not enough.
You need to define them in your code too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.!! My problem solved, I had passed a wrong argument in setContentView().